# Send information from a textfield/textarea to another php page with a css button

Tags: php, html, css, button, textbox

Okay so I'm learning php and I'm working on a little posting page to post updates.

I have the normal page already and now I'm doing the submitting.
My plan is to send the info from a textbox and textarea to savepost.php
now I want the URL arguments to be like this savepost.php?post=thetextareatext&name=nameboxtext

I want to submit this via an css button i created online.

Here's the code for the textboxes: http://pastebin.com/bsrhyxx1
I've searched on google but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: Just one suggestion . Better to use POST instead of GET.GET have some limitation like amount of data you are sending.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `<a>` tag, you should use `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`
You can style it the same way as the `<a>`tag but has the functionality to send the form. No Javascript required here.
Edit: The submit type button works in IE7 and FF 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`<a href="savepost.php" class="button">Submit</a>` to

```
<a href="#" class="button" onClick="document.getElementById('info').submit();">Submit</a>
```